# Is it possible to create a hot-standby-cluster with 2 nodes and Solaris 10?

Tags: solaris, high-availability, solaris-10

Is it possible to create a hot-standby-cluster with 2 nodes and Solaris 10?
In Linux I would use DRBD and Hearbeat/corosync, but in Solaris?

Maybe you have a tutorial?

Comment: Do you have access to the Solaris Cluster DVD ?

Comment: no, i dont have access

Comment: I always understood DRBD to be a ***cold*** standby, or "warm" at best (you can't actively use the slave device, so you have to take steps to turn your standby host into an active host during a failover). Has that changed?

Comment: Without the install media you can't build a native cluster.

Comment: i have 2solaris-machines

Comment: @voretaq7 you can use drbd pacemaker resource agent to manage that http://drbd.linbit.com/users-guide-9.0/s-pacemaker-crm-drbd-backed-service.html